# How do I generate a blowfish password hash in Ubuntu?

Tags: passwords, hash, linux, blowfish

What's the command line to generate a blowfish password hash? I can't seem to figure this out at all. Apache's ***htpasswd*** only supports bcrypt, and ***openssl passwd*** doesn't even do blowfish hahes (but it does do blowfish encryptions with ***openssl enc***).

Most sites point me to using $2a$ which is bcrypt, not blowfish ($2y$). Also a lot of places seem to confuse blowfish password hashing with blowfish file encryption. There are a lot of online sites which will generate blowfish hash for you, but I don't want to use an untrusted third party.

What other secure linux tools can I use to generate a blowfish password hash? I want to be able to define the two digit cost parameter as well as the salt.

Comment: You want bcrypt (sometimes called CRYPT_BLOWFISH) which is a password hash not blowfish which is a block cipher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bcrypt is based on blowfish. The difference between $2a$ and $2y$ is something else:

There are multiple implementations of bcrypt. And one of them, called crypt_blowfish, had a [security related bug](http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2011/q2/632h), drastically reducing the actual password space. Fixing this bug, however, caused existing bcrypt hashes to not match the passwords anymore. So this implementation started to use $2y$ to identify the fixed implementation, while still being able to maintain compatibility.

$2a$ of the original unix implementation and $2y$ of crypt_blowfish are identical.

Comment: What about the basic intention of this thread? _How to generate ... in Ubuntu?_ (though any other Linux flavour might be fine as well) As a best match on search engines this thread is pretty unsolved regarding to that point of the issue.